# Animating an Image using CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

Is it possible to create high quality animated images (like a gif) using only CSS animations, like setting the background-position-y value every 40ms?

I know that this is possible using javascript, but I would prefer using only CSS if this is possible and supported by most browsers.

Here is an example of an image I want to animate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76EMV.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using `keyframes play` and `animation` under CSS. 
You have to manipulate the background position of each frame with the FPS that you desire to keep and you will get image animated.

**For Instance,**

**1. Decide the background position**

```
@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    xxpx; }
     to { background-position: xxpx; }
}
```

**2. To make it play, with the number of seconds that you want, the steps as well as the loop**

```
    .class-name{
      -webkit-animation: play .xx steps(xx) infinite;
      -moz-animation: play .xx steps(xx) infinite;
      -ms-animation: play .xx steps(xx) infinite;
      -o-animation: play .xx steps(xx) infinite;
      animation: play .xx steps(xx) infinite;    }
```

***PS:*** xx is the dummy for any number you want to set.

Hope the helps.